# Session timeout and login

Tags: asp.net

If user has logged in and opened any page in my website and does nothing for 20 mins. Now if he selects any thing from menu or clicks any button he is redirected to login page. Now I have problem after login. The user is redirected to main page only where as I want to redirect user to the page where he wanted to go before when he clicked the menu item.

Thanks for help in advance..

Comment: To archive that, use links for your menu, and not post backs.

Answer (score 1):

This is very obvious thing that you are redirected to login page after login
I am showing you several ways to achieve this...

```
session["userid"]
```

Now when user is idle for 20 mins now at purchase.aspx :(
 So when he reload or click on any page from your navigation it will work like this

***Use this code in a page load***

---

```
if (Session["userid"] != null)
           {
// do stuff because your session is not null
}
else
{
session["previouspage"]="your page name";
response.redirect("login.aspx");
}
```

and at login page use this session to redirect to the previous page

---

Best way now if you don't want to load the session into memory another way to achieve this is

> **query string**

```
if (Session["userid"] != null)
           {
// do stuff because your session is not null
}
else
{

response.redirect("login.aspx?PreviousPage="+Your page name);
}
```

and at login page you will have a previous page with query string

request.querystring["PreviousPage"] in this your previous page will be defined

So in short you will have a previous page in this and you can redirect to that page after successful login

I hope this will help you :)

Comment: Hey thanks for reply. What if I have checked session on master page rather than checking on each page? How can I get in master page that on which page user wants to redirect. And think this code will take user to the page on which he was last and session timed out and not on page where he wanted to go.

Comment: Checking in a master page is not always good practive because page life cycle shows that it will goes to your page first and then to your master page till if you want to use it in a master page then use
`this.Request.url` in your master page..